# Swift: Can't access subclass properties in superclass array

Tags: arrays, swift, inheritance, swiftui

In the following example, I have a class `Parent` and a subclass `Child`. Next, I create an array of type `[Parent]` and fill it with a `Child`,

When I print the type of the element in the array, it prints `Child`. However, when I try to access the `name` property of that element, I can't do so because the compiler says that element is of type `Parent`.

I understand that a `Child` is of type `Parent`, but why is the compiler presenting it differently in the different print statements? How would I be able to access the `.name` property of `Child` in the array?

```
class Parent { }

class Child: Parent {
    let name = "bob"
}

var arr: [Parent] = [ Child() ]

print(type(of: arr[0]))          // Prints: "Child()"
print(arr[0].name)               // error: value of type 'Parent' has no member 'name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the statement `print(arr[0].name)`, the only type known for `arr[0]` is `Parent`, and `Parent` has no `name` property. You have to tell Swift to treat `arr[0]` as a `Child` if possible, using an `as?` cast:

```
print((arr[0] as? Child)?.name)
```

### UPDATE

`type(of: arr[0])` returns the dynamic (runtime) type of `arr[0]`, by inspecting the reference object header of `arr[0]`.

Comment: Thank you! Why does `type(of: arr[0])` return `Child`, while `arr[0].name` returns `Parent`, though? What's one doing that's different from the other?

Comment: Imagine if this was allowed. What would happen if I did `let arr = [Parent(), Child()]`, and called `print(arr[0].name)`?

Answer (score 4):

`type(of: arr[0])` is executed at the runtime, that's why it prints the type description as "Child". `arr[0].name` is executed at the compile time. Compiler only knows that `arr` is an array of `Parent` so only `Parent` properties are available.